# Volley response in Other thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I understood that volley send request in other thread but handle response in Main UI Thread . I would like to know how can I handle Volley's response in other thread or do I have to use Async Task with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: came here with the same question, but apparently the only way is to create an AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making a blocking request with the help of volley's `RequestFuture`. Like this:

```
Runnable blockingRequest = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(), future, future);
        requestQueue.add(request);

        try {
          JSONObject response = future.get(); // this will block
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // exception handling
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          // exception handling
        }
    }
};
Thread n = new Thread(blockingRequest);
n.start();
```

As you can see the response, which is blocking, will stay on the same thread, as opposed to UI thread. If you want to transfer the response to some other thread, you will need to use Thread-safe shared variables and synchronize accordingly.